# Is it possible to check the hash in the "GNU_HASH" section of an ELF executable?

Tags: linux, hash, digital-signature, elf

When I disassemble an ELF executable, I see a section `GNU_HASH` that seems to contain a hash. I think it is a signature in order to check if the executable was patched or infected by a virus.

Is there a way to check this signature ? Does Linux automatically check this signature when running the program ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When i disassemble an elf executable, i see a section that contains a
>   GNU hash. I think it is a signature in order to check if executable
>   was patch or infected by a virus.

No, it is not. You are confusing two common uses of hash functions:

- the use of [Cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) for digitally signing data, and
- the use of a (typically non-cryptographic) hash function to allow fast lookup of data, typically via a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

ELF binaries contain a "hash section" to allow fast lookup of symbols from the ELF's symbol table, to speed up linking. This section is called "hash section" because it contains a hash table. It has nothing to do with integrity checking.

To quote the ELF specification:

> Hash Table
>
> A hash table of `Elf32_Word` objects supports symbol table
>   access.

source: [SYSTEM V APPLICATION BINARY INTERFACE](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf), page 94

Comment: Details of what's in `.gnu_hash`: https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/gnu_hash_elf_sections. Note that `.gnu_hash` is different from `.hash`, and a binary can contain either, or both.

Comment: Okay so .hash contains a signature ?

Comment: @Bob5421: No, it contains a hash table. I expanded my answer.

Comment: When i type "file" command with my program as first argument, i see BuildID SHA1. Do you think this is a signature ?

Comment: @Bob5421: Please do not ask questions in comments, ask a new question. About the BuildID, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/139770/what-does-buildid-sha1-mean .